# How can I make a custom form control optionally support Material?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-material2

I have built a component in Angular named *DimensionInputComponent* that is intended to be used as a custom form control within forms. The component has some custom behavior but the template consists of just a simple `<input>` element.

I want this component to be reusable both in plain forms but also in forms using [Material](https://material.angular.io/). In our App not every form uses Material for various reasons (e.g. when only a basic and compact form is needed).

Can I make this component optionally support Material design?

Currently the component works fine in a simple form that is not using Material as in:

```
<form>
  <app-dimension-input [(ngModel)]="myData.dimension"></<app-dimension-input>
</form>
```

It does not, however, render as a Material input automatically when used like:

```
<form>
  <md-input-container>
    <app-dimension-input mdInput [(ngModel)]="myData.dimension" placeholder="Dimension"></app-dimension-input>
  </md-input-container>
</form>
```

I believe it could work if I somehow could forward the `mdInput` attribute, if set, to the component's `<input>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up solving this issue was to let the reusable component have an input switch `@Input() private useMaterialDesign = false;`. The component must then have two templates depending on the value of the switch, like so:

```
<div *ngIf="useMaterialDesign; then material else normal"></div>

<ng-template #material>
  <md-input-container>
    <input mdInput [(ngModel)]="myData.dimension" placeholder="Dimension">
  </md-input-container>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #normal>
  <input [(ngModel)]="myData.dimension" placeholder="Dimension">
</ng-template>
```

The component can now be used like this in a Material form:

```
<form>
  <app-dimension-input [(ngModel)]="myData.dimension" [useMaterialDesign]="true"></<app-dimension-input>
</form>
```

It is not the most elegant solution, so please share if anyone has a better solution and I will mark that as the answer.